# How do I downgrade my nVidia Driver in openSUSE 12.1?

Tags: drivers, opensuse, nvidia

I’m trying to trouble-shoot [a problem that I’ve been having](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25904/12940). Downgrading my nVidia driver is about the only thing I haven’t tried.

I have an nVidea GeForce 6200 and installed the latest driver version 290.10, but Í’d like to try an earlier version. When I search for my driver on the nVidia website, it always brings me to the download page for the latest version. How can I find an *older* version to install?

Here’s some potentially relevant information:

**OS Information**

```
OS:                 Linux 3.1.0-1.2-default i686
System:             openSUSE 12.1 (i586)
KDE:                4.7.2 (4.7.2) "release 5"
```

**Display Info**

```
Vendor:             nVidia Corporation
Model:              GeForce 6200 (0x0221)
2D driver:          nvidia
3D driver:          NVIDIA 290.10
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?
ftp://download.nvidia.com/opensuse/12.1/i586/

Comment: Awesome favadi. Thank you. How did you find that?

Comment: http://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories
I think you can add this repository with a few click in repository manager.